# MySQL. I stink at RegExs. Just need one to tell me if string starts with a numeral

Tags: mysql, regex

I need a MySQL query w/ Regex to tell me if my string's first character is a number from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following query returns '1', since the REGEXP matches.  You can adapt it for your purposes:

```
SELECT '123 this starts with a digit' REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]';
```

You can use it in a `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
SELECT 'a12' REGEXP '^[0-9]';
=> 0
SELECT '4ab' REGEXP '^[0-9]';
=> 1
```